# How can i download just my pdf file an not the full file path and folders

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, zip, dotnetzip

So I finally got this to work and download my pdf files into a zip file. See below:

```cs
List<string> manypaths = (List<string>)TempData["temp"];
var startpath = manypaths;

using (Ionic.Zip.ZipFile zip = new Ionic.Zip.ZipFile())
{
    zip.AddFiles(manypaths);

    MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();
    zip.Save(output);
    return File(output.ToArray(), "application/zip");
}
```

So the manypaths list variable is holding onto a few paths to the pdf file which are like `\\\\ost-stji01\pdfstorage\deposit\02_29_2019.pdf`

So when the user downloads these files they have to click through multiple folder structure i.e `ost0ji01 > pdfstorage > desposit >` then they get to their file.

My question is how can i download just the files and not the entire folder structure. SO when they open the zip file its all of the files and they don't have to go through 3 or 4 folder directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to flatten the paths in your ZIP file, use this.

```
zip.AddFiles(manypaths, @"\");
```

The second parameter of `AddFiles` allows you to specify the path of your files in the archive and `\` is the root in your archive. Therefore, all files will be located directly in your archive without subfolders.